# IIS Express - Inappropriate Hot Reload / Refresh / Postback

Tags: visual-studio, webforms, iis-express

I am running IIS Express and experiencing an inappropriate postback when:

- I merely place my cursor in the URL field in the browser; and
- I start to edit the URL (like changing one character).

I'm not pressing "enter", and I'm not trying to postback to the server, but for some reason, the debugger is so sensitive that any interaction at all with the browser's URL field triggers a refresh/postback/reload.

What is that?  Is there a way to turn that off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A guess on my part would be that you have debugging turned on for the browser.

This option:

[image]

So, try and see if script debugging is enabled.
(Disable it).

The other option?

Disable live preview. This in vs2022 is now turned on by default, and allows edits in the browser, and uses the chrome engine for rendering when you using webforms designer.

So, tools->options->Web Forms designer.
And this:
[image]

Both of above are a guess on my part, but worth a try. (So, don't use live preview, but choose Legacy Web Forms designer).

I would consider trying a different browser. Obviously on my developer computer I have several browsers like all developer’s do. So, you could try say one of your other browsers, such as these choices.

[image]

And another quick test?

Try changing your project to release, and see if that behaviour exists.

e.g., this:

[image]

So, either you have some malware in your browser, or you attached the browser session as a live debug session during debugging your code.

Comment: Thank you so much for the swift reply! I will try all these things and report back.